# Referencing list element inside of map in Kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and am still trying to learn it. I have been researching this problem for several hours now and still have not figured it out. I want to get an element from inside of a list by it's index. I figured out how to do this with a plain list, like so

```
val my_list = listOf(1,2,3)
println(my_list.get(0))
```

The above works, but when I try to do this with a list that is stored inside of a map

```
val my_list = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

my_list["set1"] = listOf(1,2,3)
my_list["set2"] = listOf("A","B","C")
my_list["set3"] = listOf("d","e","f")

val sub_list = my_list["set1"]

println(sub_list.get(0))
```

I get the following error

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
>   because of receiver type mismatch:  @InlineOnly public inline operator
>   fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map.get(key: Int): ???
>   defined in kotlin.collections @SinceKotlin public operator fun
>   MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in
>   kotlin.text

*Note: I primarily use Python, so that is what I am used to. The functionality from Python that I am trying to reproduce in Kotlin is having a dictionary of lists.*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the type declaration of your map, it should be:

```
val my_list = mutableMapOf<String, List<Any>>()
```

`Any` doesn't have a `get()` method, so there's no way to invoke it.

Even when that problem is solved, you'll probably have to deal with nullability, though, as:

```
val sub_list = my_list["set1"]
```

Will return `List<Any>?`, which means that `my_list` might not have a value for the specified key. If that's the case, you'll have to do something like:

```
sub_list?.get(0)?.run { println(it) }
```

Which in turn, could also cause an exception if the `sub_list` is empty. That could be solved with something more like:

```
vsub_list?.firstOrNull()?.run { println(it) }
```